# Pool and Tzitzis

Tags: halacha, blessing, tzitzis, tallit-katan, swimming

Do I need to make another Bracha on putting on tzitzis after I get out of the pool?

Comment: Hello UC2IC4, and welcome to mi.yodeya! Thank you for your clear and concise question. (And nice name.)

Comment: UC2IC4, was your name inspired by the first Mishnah in Maseches Sh'vuos?

Comment: UC2IC4, I've noticed that your user account on mi.yodeya.com has logged on using the same IP addresses as, and at similar times to, user accounts IshYehudi, YS, Googler, and YRU. Can you explain why this is?

Comment: You're not makpid to wear your tzitzis _in_ the pool???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is, (I do not have the source) in all situations If, at the time that he took them off, you knew that you would be putting them back on, you do not have to repeat the bracha.

Answer (score 2):

It is a machlokes Mechaber and Rema (8:14). The Mechaber says to make a new brocha, and the Rema says not to (see Mishnah Berurah 38). So, it would seem that a Sefardi should, and an Ashkenazi should not. There are more details, but this is the basic answer.

Comment: I spoke to a sfrdi he said we dont make a Bracha on a tallis Katan anyway

Comment: @user146 I think they were specifically talking about the Talit Gadol, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Ishyehudi - All Sefaradim (and Ashkenazim who wear a tallit gadol when they daven shacharit) only don't make a bracha on tallit katan because it is included in the blessing of lehitateif batzitzit.  Maybe this is talking about an Ashkenazi who is not married?